# Merge data into consistent 2d structure while iterating separate query result sets

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, multidimensional-array, merging-data

First iteration result array:

```
[
    ['id' => '25', 'distance' => 0]
]
```

Second iteration result array:

```
[
    ['id' => '24', 'distance' => 0],
    ['id' => '27', 'distance' => 0],
    ['id' => '26', 'distance' => 14.568184704048],
]
```

I am getting this response because there are multiple locations (multiple lat long), so I am getting two different arrays. How can I push all rows into a single array?

Here's my code:

```
if (
    !empty($saveArray['area'])
    && !empty($saveArray['radius'])
    || !empty($saveArray['event_name_desc'])
    || !empty($saveArray['tags'])
    || !empty($saveArray['start_date'])
    || !empty($saveArray['end_date'])
) {
    $areas = explode('|', $saveArray['area']);
    // $query = $query->where(function($query) use ($areas) {
    foreach ($areas as $are) {
        $query = Event::query();
        $latlng = explode(',', $are);
        $lat = $latlng[0];
        $lng = $latlng[1];
        $radius = $saveArray['radius'];
        $query = $query->selectRaw("id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(?)) + sin( radians(?) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ))) AS distance", [$lat, $lng, $lat])
                       ->having("distance", "<", $radius)
                       ->orderBy("distance", 'asc')
                       ->offset(0)
                       ->limit(20);
        if ($saveArray['event_name_desc']) {
            $query = $query->where('event_name', 'like', '%' . $saveArray['event_name_desc'] . '%');
            $query = $query->orWhere('event_description', 'like', '%' . $saveArray['event_name_desc'] . '%');
        }

        if ($saveArray['tags']) {
            $tags = explode(',', $saveArray['tags']);
            $query = $query->where(
                function($query) use ($tags) {
                    foreach($tags as $tag) {
                        $query->orWhere('tags', 'like', "%$tag%");
                    };
                }
            )
            ->inRandomOrder();
        }

        $events = $query->get();
        $event = json_decode(json_encode($events), true);

        $record = [];
        foreach ($event as $ls) {
            $listing['id'] = (string) $ls['id'];
            $record[] = $listing;
        }
        // $oneDimensionalArray = array_map('current', $record);
        print_r($event);
        // $multiplied = $events->map(function ($item, $key) {
        // return $item->id;
        // })->flatten();
        // print_r($multiplied);
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tries `array_merge` or collection union, collection merge methods?

Comment: this is done by myself 

i just declare array outside loop then in 2nd loop 

foreach ($event as $ls) {
                                $result[$i]['id'] = $ls['id'];
                                $i++;
                                // $listing['id'] = (String)$ls['id'];
                                // $mainArray[] = $listing;
                            }

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't going to adjust your `selectRaw()` clause to use `OR` with all of the lat/long pairs, then you can continue making iterated trips to the database (which I don't recommend).

In your current script, `$event = json_decode(json_encode($events), true);` is an indexed array of associative arrays.

Declare `$result` as an empty array before entering the parent loop. Then if you don't want to write another loop, use `array_push()` and unpack the rows using the spread operator.

```
array_push($result, ...$events);
```

Otherwise, if you are going to loop over the `$events` payload, then just push each row directly into the result array: `$result[] = $ls;`  (`$ls` is the variable name in your existing script).

As a side note, if you ever need to parse a lat-lng string into separate float -type values, `sscanf()` is more direct than `explode()` then manual casting. [Split and parse a string to create an array of associative arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71317271/2943403)