# Split and parse a string to create an array of associative arrays

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, types, split, text-parsing

How can I convert the following string into two dimensional array?

```
$coordinates = "9.499819 123.920318,9.490845 123.916563,9.484644 123.922292,9.49148 123.931519,9.499755 123.925683,9.499819 123.920318";
```

I want to separate pairs of values using the commas, then separate each pair by their delimiting space to form associative rows containing float-type values.

Desired Output:

```
$polygon = array(
    array('lat' => 9.499819, 'lng' => 123.920318),
    array('lat' => 9.490845, 'lng' => 123.916563),
    array('lat' => 9.484644, 'lng' => 123.922292),
    array('lat' => 9.49148, 'lng' => 123.931519),
    array('lat' => 9.499755, 'lng' => 123.925683),
    array('lat' => 9.499819, 'lng' => 123.920318)
);
```

Comment: Take a look at this: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: Use `explode` twice, once by `,` to get pairs, then by (space) to get individual values.

Comment: You do need to show us your best attempt at solving this yourself (code), that way we can help you. please read [ask].

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your time suggesting my problem. Hi jibsteroos, next time will surely do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a new contributor, a solution with foreach is easier to understand in my opinion.
The steps are commented in the code.

```
$coordinates = "9.499819 123.920318,9.490845 123.916563,9.484644 123.922292,9.49148 123.931519,9.499755 123.925683,9.499819 123.920318";

$polygon = explode(',',$coordinates);
/*
array (
  0 => "9.499819 123.920318",
  1 => "9.490845 123.916563",
*/

foreach($polygon as $index => $latLng){
  //The element $latLng is split into two variables with list and explode.
  list($lat,$lng) = explode(' ',$latLng);

  //The elements are replaced by a new array with the variables $lat and $lng as float
  $polygon[$index] = ['lat' => (float)$lat, 'lng' => (float)$lng];
}

//test output
echo '<pre>';
var_export($polygon);
```

output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'lat' => 9.499819,
    'lng' => 123.920318,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'lat' => 9.490845,
    'lng' => 123.916563,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'lat' => 9.484644,
    'lng' => 123.922292,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'lat' => 9.49148,
    'lng' => 123.931519,
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'lat' => 9.499755,
    'lng' => 123.925683,
  ),
  5 => 
  array (
    'lat' => 9.499819,
    'lng' => 123.920318,
  ),
)
```

Add 2022-03-04:

This one-liner with preg_match_all already returns the complete result, but with additional numeric keys.

```
preg_match_all('~(?<lat>[0-9.]+) (?<lng>[0-9.]+),?~', $coordinates, $match,PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

array_map can be used to remove the superfluous values.

```
$polygon = array_map(
  function($row){return ['lat' => $row['lat'],'lng' => $row['lng']];},
  $match
);
```

Comment: "a solution with foreach is easier to understand" - as opposed to what?

Comment: @MrWhite I think there was another solution back then using preg_match_all.

Answer (score 1):

By making iterated calls of `sscanf()`, you can dictate the data type of the parsed values and push the values into the result array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/MNjeC))

```
$coordinates = "9.499819 123.920318,9.490845 123.916563,9.484644 123.922292,9.49148 123.931519,9.499755 123.925683,9.499819 123.920318";

foreach (explode(',', $coordinates) as $i => $latLng) {
    sscanf($latLng, '%f %f', $result[$i]['lat'], $result[$i]['lng']);
};
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'lat' => 9.499819,
    'lng' => 123.920318,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'lat' => 9.490845,
    'lng' => 123.916563,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'lat' => 9.484644,
    'lng' => 123.922292,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'lat' => 9.49148,
    'lng' => 123.931519,
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'lat' => 9.499755,
    'lng' => 123.925683,
  ),
  5 => 
  array (
    'lat' => 9.499819,
    'lng' => 123.920318,
  ),
)
```